# Groovy spock test case failing which includes embeded Hazelcast in my test case

Tags: java, groovy, mockito, spock

I am new to Groovy spock test framework, trying to write my 1st test using Groovy spock. I have few questions around my below test which is keep failing, not getting what to change code to make it working???

*What I am trying is?*

1. One thing I am not understanding is when should I use mock, when
   should I use spy
2. Under **then** section I am trying to call `classUnderTest.loadFromFile()` in order to test it.
   Always I see in `CommonDataCache` class, instance variable `hazelcastCache` is always showing null while I debug  the test, but at the same time, I see `cache` is getting non-null Object. Due to this I am always getting null pointer exception as shown in below error logs.

Please anybody suggest why am I missing to make it working???

**Error log:**

```
Members [1] {
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5001 - a43cbef2-ddf7-431b-9300-2b53c3ea9294 this
}

Dec 13, 2017 3:53:53 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5001 [dev] [3.7.3] [127.0.0.1]:5001 is STARTED
Dec 13, 2017 3:53:54 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5001 [dev] [3.7.3] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...

Condition not satisfied:

commonDataCache.getFromCache("28ef4a8f-bfbc-4ad5-bc8a-88fd96ad82a8") != null
|               |                                                    |
|               null                                                 false
com.realdoc.symphony.common.CommonDataCache@144ab54


    at com.realdoc.symphony.common.store.MemoryStoreManagerTest.populate hazlecast cache from symphony dat file(MemoryStoreManagerTest.groovy:65)

Dec 13, 2017 3:53:54 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5001 [dev] [3.7.3] Running shutdown hook... Current state: ACTIVE
```

This is my Groovy test class:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Subject

import static io.dropwizard.testing.FixtureHelpers.fixture

class MemoryStoreManagerTest extends Specification {
    /**
     * Mock the any config DTOs that carries static configuration data
     **/
    def dw = Mock(SymphonyConfig)
    def cacheConfig = Mock(CacheConfig)

    /**
     * This has to be spied because there is actual call happening in the target method which converts
     * json string format to MemoryStoreFileData DTO object
     */
    def jsonUtils = Spy(JsonUtils)
    def hazelcastInstance = TestHazelcastInstanceFactory.newInstance().newHazelcastInstance()

    /**
     * This class is under test
     **/
    @Subject
    def commonDataCache = new CommonDataCache(hazelcastInstance: hazelcastInstance,hazelcastCache: hazelcastInstance.getMap("default"), config: dw)

    /**
     * This class is under test
     **/
    @Subject
    def classUnderTest = new MemoryStoreManager(dw:dw, jsonUtils: jsonUtils, commonDataCache: commonDataCache)

    /**
     * Test whether populating symphony.dat file into hazelcast cache is working
     */
    def "populate hazlecast cache from symphony dat file"() {

        setup:
            def datFile = fixture("symphony.dat")
            def resource = new ClassPathResource("symphony.dat")
            def file = resource.getFile()

        when:
            cacheConfig.getStoreLocation() >> ""
            cacheConfig.getStoreFileName() >> "symphony.dat"
            dw.getUseHazelcastCache() >> true
            dw.getCacheConfig() >> cacheConfig
            cacheConfig.getFile() >> file
            commonDataCache.postConstruct()

        then:
            classUnderTest.loadFromFile()

        expect:
            commonDataCache.getFromCache("28ef4a8f-bfbc-4ad5-bc8a-88fd96ad82a8") != null
    }
}
```

This is my target class on which I am trying to test `loadFromFile()` method

```
@Component
public class MemoryStoreManager {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MemoryStoreManager.class);


    @Autowired
    SymphonyConfig dw;

    @Autowired
    JsonUtils jsonUtils;

    @Autowired
    CommonDataCache commonDataCache;

    private final Properties properties = new Properties();

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadFromFile() {

        File file = dw.getCacheConfig().getFile();
        LOG.info("Loading Data from file-{}", file.getAbsolutePath());

        FileInputStream inStream = null;
        try {

            if (!file.exists()) {
                Files.createFile(file.toPath());
            }

            inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            properties.load(inStream);

            String property = properties.getProperty("data");

            MemoryStoreFileData fileData;

            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(property)) {
                fileData = jsonUtils.jsonToObject(property, MemoryStoreFileData.class);
            } else {
                fileData = new MemoryStoreFileData(Collections.emptyMap(), Collections.emptyMap());
            }

            Long lastUpdatedTimeInFile = fileData.getLastUpdatedTime();
            LOG.info("Last updated time in File-{}", lastUpdatedTimeInFile);
            Long lastUpdatedTimeInCache = (Long) commonDataCache.getFromCache("lastUpdatedTime");
            LOG.info("Last updated time in Cache-{}", lastUpdatedTimeInCache);

            Map<String, DocData> loadedMap = fileData.getDocDataMap();
            if (MapUtils.isEmpty(loadedMap)) {
                loadedMap = new HashMap<>();
            }

            Map<String, ProcessStatusDto> processStatusMap = fileData.getProcessStatusMap();

            if (MapUtils.isEmpty(processStatusMap)) {
                processStatusMap = new HashMap<>();
            }

            if (lastUpdatedTimeInFile != null && (lastUpdatedTimeInCache == null || lastUpdatedTimeInCache < lastUpdatedTimeInFile)) {
                LOG.info("Overwriting data from File");
                commonDataCache.addAllToCache(loadedMap, processStatusMap);
            } else {
                String requestId;
                DocData fileDocData;
                DocData cacheDocData;
                Map<String, String> filePageStatusMap;
                Map<String, String> cachePageStatusMap;
                String pageId;
                String fileStatus;
                String cacheStatus;
                for (Entry<String, DocData> entry : loadedMap.entrySet()) {
                    requestId = entry.getKey();
                    fileDocData = entry.getValue();
                    cacheDocData = (DocData) commonDataCache.getFromCache(requestId);
                    filePageStatusMap = fileDocData.getPageStatusMap();
                    cachePageStatusMap = cacheDocData.getPageStatusMap();
                    for (Entry<String, String> pageStatus : filePageStatusMap.entrySet()) {
                        pageId = pageStatus.getKey();
                        fileStatus = pageStatus.getValue();
                        cacheStatus = cachePageStatusMap.get(pageId);

                        if (StringUtils.equals("IN_PROCESS", cacheStatus) && !StringUtils.equals("IN_PROCESS", fileStatus)) {
                            cachePageStatusMap.put(pageId, fileStatus);
                            LOG.info("PageId: {} status: {} updated", pageId, fileStatus);
                        }
                    }

                    commonDataCache.addToCache(requestId, cacheDocData);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("ErrorCode-{}, Component-{}, Message-{}. Error Loading cache data from file-{}. Exiting system", "OR-51010", "ORCHESTRATION", "Symphony cache loading exception", file.getAbsoluteFile(), e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my cache utility class where store and retrieve methods are defines.

```
@Component
public class CommonDataCache {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommonDataCache.class);

    @Autowired
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    @Autowired
    SymphonyConfig config;

    public static String LAST_UPDATED_TIME = "lastUpdatedTime";
    private IMap<String, Object> hazelcastCache = null;
    private boolean useHazelcast = false;

    private final Map<String, Object> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        hazelcastCache = hazelcastInstance.getMap("default");

        // Enable only if logging level is DEBUG
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            hazelcastCache.addEntryListener(new HazelcastMapListener(), true);
        }
        useHazelcast = config.getUseHazelcastCache();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAllDataFromCache() {
        return hazelcastCache;
    }

    public void addToCache(String key, Object value) {
        if (useHazelcast) {
            hazelcastCache.put(key, value);
            hazelcastCache.put(LAST_UPDATED_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
        } else {
            cache.put(key, value);
            cache.put(LAST_UPDATED_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }

    public Object getAndRemoveFromCache(String key) {
        if (useHazelcast) {
            return hazelcastCache.remove(key);
        } else {
            return cache.remove(key);
        }
    }

    public Object getFromCache(String key) {
        if (useHazelcast) {
            return hazelcastCache.get(key);
        } else {
            return cache.get(key);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param cacheDataMap
     */
    public void addAllToCache(Map<String, DocData> cacheDataMap, Map<String, ProcessStatusDto> processStatusMap) {
        hazelcastCache.putAll(cacheDataMap);
        hazelcastCache.putAll(processStatusMap);
        hazelcastCache.put(LAST_UPDATED_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void lockKey(String key) {
        if (useHazelcast) {
            hazelcastCache.lock(key);
        }
    }

    public void unlockKey(String key) {
        if (useHazelcast) {
            hazelcastCache.unlock(key);
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getByKeyContains(String keyString) {

        Map<String, Object> values;
        if (useHazelcast) {
            Set<String> foundKeys = hazelcastCache.keySet(entry -> ((String)entry.getKey()).contains(keyString));
            values = hazelcastCache.getAll(foundKeys);
        } else {
            values = Maps.filterEntries(cache, entry -> entry.getKey().contains(keyString));
        }
        return values;
    }

}
```

Here is maven dependencies for groovy tests.

```
        <!-- Dependencies for GROOVY TEST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GROOVY TEST FRAMEWORK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>realdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${realdoc.dropwizard-spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <!-- any version of Groovy \>= 1.5.0 should work here -->
            <version>${groovy-all.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib-nodep.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GROOVY TEST FRAMEWORK -->



        <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        ...
        ...
        </build>
```

Comment: I got the solution, updating the above test case with working one.

Comment: You test looks strange, most of your `when` code belongs in the `given`. `given`=prepare state/stub responses, `when`=action that is tested, `then`=verify that the correct thing did happen, `expect`=is an alternative to `when-then` or to check preconditions not like you use it here. Furthermore, don't use mocks if it is a simple Pojo just use the getter/setters.

Comment: Its expected, as I am pretty new, no right idea what to use where, I understood a bit about given, when, and then from your comments. But still not where what is difference between then and expect? and other doubt I have is, I tried using setter/getter instead mock, get some Null pointer exception at this like `File file = dw.getCacheConfig().getFile();` as this calls internally `Path.get(storeFileName, storeFileName).toFile()`. This is the reason I created Mock, with that my NPE errors got fixed. I am not sure what I did is right???

Comment: Check out the docs about the blocks http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_blocks and sure it is correct to use a `Stub`/`Mock` if you need to stub a method call. I meant if you have a simple Pojo there is not need to mock it, but what you described is not a simple Pojo so its ok.

Comment: Thanks @leonard documentation link is helpful.